# Refresh select options in angular utilizing two selects

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this select:

**Template:**

```
<div class="select">
  <select (change)="getIdTipoVariacao(item.value.tipo)" formControlName="tipo" class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{item.value.tipo || 'Tipo da Variação'}}</option>
    <option [hidden]="item.value.tipo == tipoVariacao.valor" *ngFor="let tipoVariacao of tiposvariacoes;let j = index"
      class="dropdown-item">{{tipoVariacao.valor}}</option>
  </select>


  <span class="select-highlight"></span>
  <span class="select-bar"></span>
</div>
```

In my component, throught the function getIdTipoVariacao() i catch the id of my "variacao" selected:

```
getIdTipoVariacao(variacao:string) { // take the id of one "tipo de variação" to send to function get-lista-valor-atributo to get the list of attributs of my "variation":
    for(let i=0;i<this.tiposvariacoes.length;i++){
      if(this.tiposvariacoes[i].valor == variacao){
        this.idTipoVariacao = this.tiposvariacoes[i].id
      }
    }
this.listaValoresAtributo(this.idTipoVariacao);
}

  listaValoresAtributo(id: number){
    console.log(id)
    this.tipoProdutoService.listaValoresAtributo(id)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.listaAtributos = res.data.valores_atributos;
        this.loadingfiltro = false;
      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          if (err.status == 401) {
            this.authService.Logout();
          }

          if (err.error.data.erro) {
            this.toastrService.showToast(false, 'Ops, temos um problema', err.error.data.erro);
          } else {
            this.toastrService.showToast(false, 'Ops, temos um problema', 'Entre em contato com o suporte!');
          }
        })
  }
```

Everythings work well, this function take the id of my variation and send to my backend, that me returns an array (this.listaAtributos), i have to copulate the other select.

In my second select i do one ngfor trying to copulate the options according the answer of my server, but no one data is copulate. If i print a console.log in this.listaAtributos, i see my array with my data that i need to coppulate. How can i do this?

My second select:

```
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="select">
          <select formControlName="valor" class="select-text">
            <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{item.value.valor || 'Valor'}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let ValorAtributo of listaAtributos;let x = index"
              class="dropdown-item">{{ValorAtributo.valor}}</option>
          </select>


          <span class="select-highlight"></span>
          <span class="select-bar"></span>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Observables? Someone can teach me?

Comment: What do you see in the options ?

Comment: my options is empty

Comment: Your code is looking fine to me. Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Can you verify if the listaAtributos is actually a list(array) and not an object